# How does the DEADQ work for SVRCONN channel in MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

i've a question about the DEADQ in MQ. I know that DEADQ has been used when the msg cannot be delived into the target queue, for example queue full or put inhibited like this. But if the client applicatoin connects to QMGR through **SVRCONN** channel and that target queue is full right now, will the msg sent by client application go to DEADQ or just that put operation would return with failure saying queue full?

if it works as the latter, does it mean the DEADQ not being used for client-server mode, like through SVRCONN channel?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DLQ is used by QMgr-to-QMgr channels because at that point the message has been entrusted to WMQ to deliver and/or persist as necessary.  There is no option to directly notify the sending application in the API call that something went wrong.  Best the QMgr can do is to send back a report message, if the app has requested it, and if the app specified a reply-to queue.

When an application is connected over a client channel the QMgr can tell the application during the PUT API call "hey, the destination queue is full," and let the application decide the appropriate course of action.  Usually that "correct action" does NOT include putting the message onto the DLQ.  In fact, routing this type of message to a secondary queue is VERY unusual.  Conventional wisdom says it's better for the app to raise an alert than to provision overflow queues.

The one exception to this is when using JMS classes.  These will move a poison message (one where the backout count exceeds the BOTHRESH value on the queue) to a backout queue.  If the backout queue is not specified or the app is not authorized to it or if it is full, the app will then try to use the DLQ.  Again, allowing an app to directly put messages to the DLQ is very unusual and not considered good practice, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rob. So for the client-QMgr mode, the MCA would not reroute the msg to DEADQ once not be able to deliver target queue. But that QMgr-to-QMgr MCA can do, Right?

Comment: Yes.  The QMgr-to-QMgr MCA has some logic for that.  Other than some failover logic, the client MCA is mostly just a proxy for the application to make API calls and does not attempt to inject its own behaviors.  Even the poison message processing I mentioned is not the client MCA.  That is in fact in the Java/JMS classes.